# Cannot compile with Eigen Library

Tags: c++, linux, eigen

I am writing a `C++` application on `Linux`.

For a particular task I need to include the `Eigen` library.

I installed the `libeigen3-dev` packages and I include it in my code in this way:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
```

I then try to compile this file with the command:

```
g++    -I/usr/include/eigen3 -c TetrisAgent.cpp -o TetrisAgent.o
```

I'm using `gcc version 4.7.2`.

Unfortunately, I am not able to compile it, due to this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:329:0,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from TetrisAgent.cpp:24:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/GeneralProduct.h:121:14: error: expected ‘>’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/GeneralProduct.h:121:56: error: ‘N’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/GeneralProduct.h:121:59: error: template argument 2 is invalid
make: *** [TetrisAgent.o] Error 1
```

Can anyone help me fixing it?

**EDIT:** 
This is to answer Albert question "*You very probably already have the error in your own code (TetrisAgent.cpp) before the include. Can you add all the code up to the include, i.e. the first 24 lines?*"

```
/* 
* Copyright (C) 2008, Brian Tanner

 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
 */

#include <stdio.h>  /* for printf */
#include <string.h> /* for strcmp */
#include <time.h> /*for time()*/
#include <rlglue/Agent_common.h> /* agent_ function prototypes and RL-Glue types */
#include <rlglue/utils/C/RLStruct_util.h> /* helpful functions for allocating structs and cleaning them up */
#include "tetris_utils.h"
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
```

**EDIT 2**: this is the code of the `tetris_utils.h` file:

```
#define GRID_WIDTH 10
#define GRID_HEIGHT 20
#define BATCH_SIZE 100

//number of games before updating the weights
#define M 10

static int available_rotations[] = {1,3,3,0,1,1,3};

static int max_position[7][4] = {{10,7,0,0}, 
                                {9,8,9,8}, 
                                {9,8,9,8}, 
                                {9,0,0,0}, 
                                {8,9,0,0}, 
                                {8,9,0,0}, 
                                {8,9,8,9} };


struct state_dump{
    int features[21];
    float V;
    float reward;
};
```

Comment: You very probably already have the error in your own code (TetrisAgent.cpp) before the include. Can you add all the code up to the include, i.e. the first 24 lines?

Comment: There might still be some error in your tetris_utils.h. But have you tried to put the Eigen/Dense include at the top? Also, in addition, try to put your own include at the bottom (that is in general a good advice). Do you get the same errors?

Comment: Try the -E option and see what the offending line was preprocessed to.

Comment: Albert, you were right. I inverted the order of the include statement (now Eigen comes just before tetris_utils.h) and it compiles without problem. But I really do not understand what is the problem. I'll paste the code of the library, could you give a look?

Comment: Marc, I tried to add the -E flag but it dispays no output :(

Comment: Maybe one of your defines is conflicting with Eigen?

Comment: @Aslan986 Your use of macros is suspicious and may interfere with other libraries. Try changing each macro to a constant integer. That is #define GRID_WIDTH 10 will become const int grid_width = 10;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define M 10
```

^ Redefining an individual letter without respect for scope is a bad idea.

Try `static int const M = 10;` instead.